# Not able to change brightness on a Compaq Presario CQ61

Tags: networking, grub2, brightness, compaq

Here is my result of lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
joydev                 17393  0 
vesafb                 13516  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      60251  1 
snd_hda_intel          32765  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80845  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
nvidia              10958194  42 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k                 117425  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
mac80211              436455  1 ath9k
bnep                   17830  2 
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
uvcvideo               67203  0 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
parport_pc             32114  0 
ath9k_common           13781  1 ath9k
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
psmouse                87213  0 
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
bluetooth             158438  8 bnep,rfcomm
ppdev                  12849  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
ath9k_hw              391523  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    19387  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
mac_hid                13077  0 
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
cfg80211              178679  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
snd                    62064  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
r8169                  56321  0 
usbhid                 41906  0 
hid                    77367  1 usbhid
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work as mine's a Samsung but I use this command:

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=XX
```

where `XX` is a hex value, but don't press 00 because you wouldn't see anything then. I cannot get it to work on restart though.